# Modify Enunciate generated configuration file to use the latest jackson library for CXF

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jackson, enunciate

`Enunciate` generates the `cxf-jaxrs-servlet.xml` file automatically and specifies: `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` as the `JAX-RS` provider.  This class has changed to `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` in the latest `Jackson` library.  How can I make `Enunciate` specify the new class as the `JSON` provider in the automatically generated file? Or can I make `Enunciate` to use a user provided `XML` file?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and am using Maven with Spring. I was able to solve this by using the [maven replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) and setting it to overwrite the org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider in jaxrs:providers and replacing it with com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not a good way to do that at the moment. We're tracking support for Jackson 2 at [ENUNCIATE-719](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-719).